# How to force view in browser of pdf and word docs

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am required to open various files types such as pdf and word in browser I see that the most accepted solution seems to be the simlar as to what I have done

```
public string GetDocument(Guid UserId, string Filename)
{
  string mimeType = "application/pdf"
  Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + fileName);
return File(doc, mimeType);
}
```

My quesiton is how do i turn my raw file on the server to something that can be served to the browser I persume I have to change it to byte if so how would one change a pdf to bytes. And for that matter word files

Comment: IIRC, you have to have office on the server itself. Which is apparently a bad thing.

Comment: @Kramb figured be some dam microsoft limitation but onto my other point how do i convert a file to a byte i persume that would also need to be done

Comment: @dave It's not a Microsoft limitation. It's the way web browsers work. Browsers don't have native renderers for Word files. So you need to either research one such as Google Docs or create one yourself. No, Office is not necessarily required.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
public void GetDocument(Guid UserId, string Filename)
{
  string mimeType = "application/pdf"
  Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + fileName);
  Response.WriteFile(fileName);
  Response.End();
}
```

Note, Response.WriteFile expects the FULL path to the file, so if the filename variable isn't the full path, you'll need to map it.

In the case of the PDF, most browsers will open in inside the browser, for other file types your mileage may vary, depending on whether the browser has the capability to display that file type inline.

Comment: thanks for the answer in that respect. Its manly words docs and pdfs I have to worry about in this secneraio

Answer (score 0):

You cannot force it from the server end.

Some browsers (such as Chrome) can render a PDF just fine, but a PDF rendered from a server will only open in Chrome only if the .pdf file extension is associated with Chrome.  You can't change the associations without access to the machine on which the browser is running.

As far as I know, you cannot open a Word doc directly in any browser.  You have to use a viewer.

Using a viewer you can display PDF or Word docs within the page-- this is different from downloading the file and displaying it natively, but it may suit your purpose.

A few viewers are freely available.  Here's two.

[Google docs viewer](http://www.gtricks.com/google-docs-tricks/read-embed-documents-online-google-docs-viewer/)

[Office Web Apps viewer](http://www.labnol.org/internet/google-docs-viewer-alternative/26591/)